# Does using AJAX on your website drop your page views while ranking?

Tags: ajax, single-page-application

Since its related to AJAX technology so I thought this is the best place to ask.

I am displaying 5 articles at a time to the user on my website and when he clicks 'Next' I load the next 5 articles using AJAX without loading the entire page.The result is that he always stays at the same page .

One of my friend told me that website ranking depends on number of page views and I think this obviously reduce my page views.

Should I not use AJAX then?

(This might be a stupid question but I seriously have no idea about ranking and SEO so please help)

Answer (score 0):

By loading your content dynamically Google will not see the entire page. Only the part that is loaded. So, if Google rank is important for you it's better to not use an infinity loader.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not a good idea to navigate page using AJAX. Consider a scenario,

display 5 articles first then by clicking **Next** button, next 5 items will load and so on... by using this the page will not become Search engine friendly.

in this case search engine can't locate your contents exactly and will crawl only initial contents.

but with some efforts you can make ajax navigation search engine friendly.. see [example here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?csw=1).

Currently the scheme of loading content of page dynamically is not a good idea for SEO friendly web page but try considering other ajax page navigation schemes that might help the page to make dynamic as well as search engine friendly.

some suggested ajax navigation schemes are listed below,

http://nickjohnson.com/b/how-to-make-ajax-search-engine-friendly-seo

http://ajax.rswebanalytics.com/

http://www.symatix.co.uk/articles/ajax/search-engine-friendly-ajax-navigation