# Efficient way of passing data and calling background script in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page where I show 5 questions to a user and when he clicks on **Next 5** link I am sending the score of current page `onbeforeunload()` to the script `updateScore()` asynchronously using jQuery AJAX and when the call is successful the next 5 questions are displayed.

```
window.onbeforeunload=function()
            {
                $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "updateScore.php",
                      data: "pageScore="+score,
                      cache: false,
                      timeout:5000,
                      async:false
                });
            }
```

But the problem is that on slow connections,it might hang the browser for a while until AJAX call returns successfully.When I tried `async:true`(default) the next page is loaded first without making call to `updateScore.php`.It might be due to the fact that connection is fast in localhost hence giving no time for the `AJAX` call to complete.This was the reason I used `async:false`.Will it happen (making no AJAX call) if I use `async:true` in practical case as well?If yes, is there a way to come around this problem?

Comment: why are you using `onbeforeunload` event in the first place? cant you use regular methods of binding an `a` element and to get the next five quesition on JSON format which is quicker and have nicer look (the user never leaves the current page, hence all the side scripts, css, etc loading only one time)

Comment: I agree to @JohnnyJS. And you are doing double job here... Instead of sending data with POST u send it via ajax and then reload anyway...

Comment: @JohnnyJS : This is due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230158/does-using-ajax-on-your-website-drop-your-page-views-while-ranking asked earlier by me.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to change your code a bit.

Make ajax request on "click" event, and redirect user inside ajax callback function.

Like this:

```
$('#mybutton').on('click', function()
{
  $('#pleasewait').show();
  $ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "updateScore.php",
    data: "pageScore="+score,
    success: function() { document.location="nextpage.php" }
  });
}
```